# Complicated SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem writing a SQL query, can someone help me plz ?

I have a table called `Day`, in every day there are many `Hour` lines,

Example :

Day 1 got many lines:

```
Line1- hour = 3
Line2- hour = 2
Line3- hour = 6
Line4 ...
```

Day 2 got many lines:

```
Line1- hour = 7
Line2- hour = 3
Line3- hour = 1
Line4 ...
```

...

I want to do a query that select the max hour in each day (Day 1, Day 2, ... Day 300), and do the sum of all those max values.

Can you help me plz ?

Comment: -1 This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: What RDMS are you using and what version?

Comment: I'm using Mysql, thx for help. iamnotmaynard, not my problem if u don't like "plz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM((SELECT MAX(hour) FROM days)), day FROM days GROUP BY day
```

*may* work. It would help if you would post your actual database structure